# Can i cast the four bytes of a uint32_t to uint8_t pointers

Tags: pointers, casting, stm32, hal

Some background:

I'm using STM32 to receive and transmit a long 24 bit signal that can determine whether batteries are overly discharged or overly charged, and monitor temperatures through an AFE.

The actual problem:

The function I need to use in one of the STM libraries takes an argument of an 8-bit pointer: `HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&buf_ptr, 1, 100);` in order to interface with the 24-bit AFE. I aim to write a 32-bit signal that can encode the data I need, and just call the function 3 times and reference the 32-bit signal with an 8-bit pointer, but I was wondering what the simplest solution to my problem would be.

My first hope was that I could access the first byte of information with an 8-bit pointer and then increment the address by one each time:

```cpp
void MAX_Interface::MOSI_BufTransmit()
{
    uint8_t* buf_ptr = (uint8_t) &OBuf;

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&buf_ptr, 1, 100);
        buf_ptr++;
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

My second idea is that maybe I could bit-shift the output buffer over by 8 bits each time and then cast that to a byte:

```cpp
void MAX_Interface::MOSI_BufTransmit()
{
    uint8_t* buf_ptr

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        buf_ptr =(uint8_t*) OBuf>>8*i;
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&buf_ptr, 1, 100);
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

I feel like these could be the most elegant solutions, but neither of these work.

Does anyone know more about this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the individual bytes of a 32-bit integer is fine.

However, both of your approaches fail to work because you are passing the wrong memory address to `HAL_SPI_Transmit()`. You are passing the address of `buf_ptr` itself, rather than the address of `OBuf` that `buf_ptr` is pointing at.

Also, in the case of the second approach, you are not even assigning `buf_ptr` to point at a valid memory address to begin with!  You are reading the *values* of the individual bytes of `OBuf` and casting them to pointers, rather than taking the *address* of each byte.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void MAX_Interface::MOSI_BufTransmit()
{
    uint8_t* buf_ptr = (uint8_t*) &OBuf;

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, buf_ptr+i, 1, 100); // or: &buf_ptr[i]
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

That being said, the 3rd parameter of `HAL_SPI_Transmit()` is a byte count, so you might try simply asking `HAL_SPI_Transmit()` to send all 3 bytes in one go, instead of calling `HAL_SPI_Transmit()` 3 times to send 1 byte at a time, eg:

```cpp
void MAX_Interface::MOSI_BufTransmit()
{
    uint8_t* buf_ptr = (uint8_t*) &OBuf;

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, buf_ptr, 3, 100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

Comment: your code is unfortunatelly wrong you deassert cs pin too early. You should wait for the BSY flag.

Comment: I don't know anything about how the STM32 works, my answer is strictly regarding the code provided and the question asked.

Comment: @0___________ Busy flag is checked inside `HAL_SPI_Transmit`.